# Renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a parent Spring Boot project and child jar as a dependency.
Both projects have `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign` as a dependency.

During startup I get error:

```
Description:

The bean 'child-project.FeignClientSpecification' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

What are the possible ways to fix this issue except adding `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` into applicatiomm.yml file??

Answer (score 0):

Having both the parent Spring Boot project and child jar depend on `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign` can lead to a situation called **"dependency conflicts"**. This happens when libraries with the same name and different versions attempt to exist within the same application classpath.

Ensure both the parent project and child jar explicitly declare the same version of `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign`. I hope this resolve the issue.